# Can someone provide a source for the claim that MI5 paid Mussolini to do pro-war propaganda?

Tags: world-war-one, mussolini

[This](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2009/oct/13/benito-mussolini-recruited-mi5-italy) 2009 Guardian article claims that Mussolini was paid 100 £ per week during War World I to write pro-war propaganda articles on his newspaper "Il Popolo D'Italia".

The article is reportedly based on the work of Peter Martland according to Wikipedia former historian of Cambridge University.

The story seems plausible, however, I can not find on the web any reference besides newspaper articles.
[This](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1220263/MI5-paid-Benito-Mussolini--6-000-week-peddle-British-propaganda.html) Daily Mail article states *"Dr Martland's findings were included in Christopher Andrew's history of MI5, Defence of the Realm, published last week."*

However, a quick search of the word "Mussolini" into "Defence of the Realm by Christopher" Andrew results in:

*"Hoare’s counter-subversion operations included bribing pro-Allied journalists, among them the former socialist Benito Mussolini, who in 1919 was to found the Fascist movement. Hoare paid Mussolini the then considerable sum of £100 a week.<sup>119</sup>"*

with note 119 being:

*"<sup>119</sup> CUL Templewood Papers, Part III, Italy and the Vatican 1917–1918, files 1–5. Hoare’s other tasks in Rome included counter-espionage and curtailing the extensive contraband activities (especially flows of specie and other prohibited goods to and from Germany through Switzerland)."*

So the book seems not to refer to Dr Martland work but directly to the  [Templewood Papers](https://www.lib.cam.ac.uk/collections/departments/manuscripts-university-archives/significant-archival-collections/templewood) which are not available online.

The question is:
Can someone provide a source for the claim that MI5 paid Mussolini to do pro-war propaganda? Maybe a reference to Martland's research or some passage of Templewood Papers.